# Can't excute command in Singularity image with Nextflow

Tags: singularity-container, nextflow

I'm trying to do a simple process, create the `a.txt` file in `$projectDir/Result` directory **with a singularity container**.

My working dir:

- touch.nf
- nextflow.config
- a.txt (I want to create)

This is my nextflow script `touch.nf`:

```
#!/user/bin/env nextflow

process TOUCH{

    publishDir "./Result", mode: 'copy'

    debug true

    output:
    path "*"

    """
    touch a.txt
    """
}

workflow{
    TOUCH()
}
```

And this is my `nextflow.config`:

```
singularity{
    enabled = true
    
}


process{
    withName:TOUCH {
        container = "docker://continuumio/miniconda3"
    }
}
```

The output with error:

```
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 23.04.2
Launching `fastqc.nf` [kickass_swanson] DSL2 - revision: cc21d1cf79
[-        ] process > TOUCH -
Pulling Singularity image docker://continuumio/miniconda3 [cache .../work/singularity/continuumio-miniconda3.img]
[-        ] process > TOUCH [  0%] 0 of 1

...

ERROR ~ Error executing process > 'TOUCH'

Caused by:
  Process `TOUCH` terminated with an error exit status (1)

Command executed:

  touch a.txt

Command exit status:
  1

Command output:
  (empty)

Command error:
  /bin/bash: .command.sh: No such file or directory

Work dir:
  ...

Tip: view the complete command output by changing to the process work dir and entering the command `cat .command.out`

 -- Check '.nextflow.log' file for details
```

Why can't Nextflow execute the command by singularity container? I really need some help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have found my answer in [this issue](https://github.com/nextflow-io/nextflow/issues/1732). Just make a little change in the singularity configuration file.

```
singularity{
    enabled = true
    runOptions = "--bind $PWD"
}
```